# SQL syntax for Same Date Last Year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following T-SQL query which pulls data from a View Table:

```
SELECT * from MyView

WHERE StayDate >= '2014-07-01'
```

I need to add a filter to this query that will be applied on a field called "CreatedOn" (it is datetime field). The filter needs to filter the "CreatedOn" based on the SAME DATE LAST YEAR.

Thus, if today's date is '2015-10-26', my query should look this:

```
SELECT * from MyView

WHERE StayDate >= '2014-07-01'

AND CreatedOn <= '2014-10-26'
```

Since this query will be used in a PowerPivot environment, I am thinking along these lines:

```
SELECT * from MyView

WHERE StayDate >= '2014-07-01'

AND CreatedOn <= getdate()
```

How do I modify the getdate() part so that it becomes the Same Date Last Year?

Comment: `DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the date a year before the current date, you could use:

```
DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
```

However, since that includes the time component, there's a possibility that some records will be left out. You should use this instead:

```
< DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', GETDATE())))
```

The above will return the date a year before the current plus one day. That is, if today's date is `'2015-10-26`', the above will return `'2014-10-27'`. Note that this will be without a time component and you should be using `<` for the comparison.

---

[More common date routines.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/lynnpettis/2009/03/25/some-common-date-routines/)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT getdate() - 365
```

i.e,

```
SELECT * from MyView

WHERE StayDate >= '2014-07-01'

AND CreatedOn <= getdate() - 365
```

Edit: Not applicable for leap year. Thank you @mechnicov.

Comment: My bad. You are right that this is not 100 % solution but quick one which had matched my requirement where it did not mattered for leap year.